# Find duplicate value in multiple column

Tags: excel, exception, excel-formula, vba

I have 7 column having text value. I want to find common value that present in all seven column.

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  Answer 
Q   Q   Q   Q   Q   Q   Q   Q
W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W
E   E   E   W   W   R   R   not found
D   D   D   D   D   D   Q   not found
```

**EDIT**:

I have tried with below coding

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $B$2:$B$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $C$2:$C$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $D$2:$D$4, 0)), $A2, ""), ""), "")
```

Comment: I have tried with below coding                      =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $B$2:$B$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $C$2:$C$4, 0)), IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2, $D$2:$D$4, 0)), $A2, ""), ""), "")

Comment: FYI your comment should instead be edited into your OP, with code tags (`{}`).  It reads better, and also shows us that you've tried something (which we all appreciate!).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A1 is in A1, in H2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:G2,A2)=7,A2,"not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this in your "Answer" column:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,A2=C2,A2=D2,A2=E2,A2=F2,A2=G2),G2,"not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

while the answer from pnuts is better (to my eye) you also could do it like this:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2:G2),A2,"not found")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.